# .net config file AppSettings: NameValueCollection vs. KeyValueConfigurationCollection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, configuration, app-config

When accessing the current application's appSettings, I get a NameValueCollection:

```
NameValueCollection settings =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
```

When accessing another application's appSettings, I get a KeyValueConfigurationCollection:

```
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(sExe).AppSettings.Settings;
```

---

1. Is there a reason why these two methods ([ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) and [AppSettingsSection.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.settings.aspx)) have similar but different (and incompatible) return types? Maybe I'm using an outdated method in one of the two cases?
2. Is there an easy way to get the same type in both cases, i.e., to get a NameValueCollection for another application's appSettings or a KeyValueConfigurationCollection for the currently running application's appSettings?

---

**Update**: For question 2, I've found the following way to get the configuration of the *currently running* (non-web) application as a KeyValueConfigurationCollection:

```
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = 
    Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None).AppSettings.Settings;
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the suggested answer (the Update) in the OP doesn't work in a _web_ application :~(

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Good point, thanks. I've updated my answer-inside-the-question. Unfortunately, I don't know a solution for web applications.

Comment: i'll add one later :)  I got it covered..

Comment: old as it is, a quick FYI... Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(null) does the same default behavior as ConfigurationManager.AppSettings... types aren't compatible, but if you reflect into the OpenExeConfiguration overloads, you'll see that NULL is a very valid option for default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are trying to solve the same problem and they're compatible with the same configuration schema, but the difference resides in the fact that both have evolved in different development times, as you said.

But it's not about you're using outdated versions. Those are different ways of getting the same result. Maybe you can't figure why, but the point is sometimes you need to obtain your configuration from different sources, so make sense having these options.

<strike>Answering your second question, you can implement an extension method for both return types converting them to a common type.</strike>

For example, if you want NameValueCollection you can implement that:

```
public static NameValueCollection ToCollection(this KeyValueConfigurationCollection source)
{
       // An iterator to create a NameValueCollection here and return it.
}
```

Or if you want KeyValueConfigurationCollection, you can do the same, but for returning instances of this type.

Then, when you want AppSettings, you can do `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ToCollection();` and/or  `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(sExe).AppSettings.Settings.ToCollection();`.
**Check author's answer edit! This part of my answer is wrong and useless :) Thanks.**

In fact, name-value collections are someway outdated because are from .net 1.x days. But it's not obsolete, because this is the way of doing it (for now).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. About the conversion thing: I think I've found an easier solution for this, see the update to my question.

Comment: Oops! That's true, sorry for this mistake! Having that solution that extension method becomes useless and a wheel reinvention :)

Comment: Preferring the dependency on System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection over System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationCollection frees your component from expecting named values in a configuration section.